# how can I call WinUsb_WritePipe method in C# without issue

Tags: c#, winusb

I have an issue when calling the 'WinUsb_WritePipe' method.

At first, I start by call 'CreateFile' method that provides me a handle.
Then I call 'WinUsb_Initialize' method to get the WinUsbHandle.

After that, I retrieve some information about my USB device by calling 'WinUsb_QueryDeviceInformation', 'WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings' and 'WinUsb_QueryPipe' without any issue.

My problem appends when I have to call the 'WinUsb_WritePipe' method.
In a first library that I have made in C language, it works correctly.
But I have to switch from C to C# for my new library and the method returns False and the last error that I get is INVALID_PARAMETER.

It seems that comes from overlapped parameter. I can't passed NULL to this parameter as indicated in the specification.

I don't see what I am doing wrong.

I've tried already:

- I already try to change the type of Overlapped parameter from IntPtr, to Int to put 0 as for C language call.
- I have tried to change IntPtr by NativeOverlapped structure. In a first time with a NULL structure but I have the same issue.
- If I gave a initialized structure, I try to call GetOverlappedResult method but it just returns INVALID_PARAMETER so the issue is always present.
- I have tried to use unsafe to manage the method as a C calling but the issue is still here.

You can find my code below :

```
[DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern Boolean WinUsb_WritePipe(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, Byte PipeId, Byte[] Buffer, UInt32 BufferLength, ref UInt32 LengthTransferred,  IntPtr Overlapped);


Byte[] SendBuffer = new Byte[3];

SendBuffer[0] = 0x01;

SendBuffer[1] = 0x0D;

SendBuffer[2] = 0x00;

UInt32 BytesToWrite = Convert.ToUInt32(SendBuffer.Length);

UInt32 BytesWritten=0;

IntPtr Handle = DeviceUSB.GetHandle(); //corresponding to the WinUsbHandle

Byte Pipe = DeviceUSB.GetPipe(DeviceUSB.GetSelectedMode()).PipeOutId; // 0x04

Success = WinUsbApiCalls.WinUsb_WritePipe(Handle, Pipe, SendBuffer, SizeToSend, ref SizeSent, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I expect the return value is set to true and SizeSent to be 3. but the actual returns false with lastError set to INVALID_PARAMETER and SizeSent is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried again with my first declaration of DllImport with UInt32 instead of UInt64. There is no exception of stack imbalance but just an error by getting last error which is INVALID_PARAMETER. I think there is an issue with overlapped param and not with types of size parameters. It seems that it is not supported by writepipe method to put IntPtr.Zero into this param overlapped.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winusb/nf-winusb-winusb_writepipe you need to change your BufferLength and LengthTransferred parameters from **UInt32** to **UInt64**

```
C++
BOOL WinUsb_WritePipe(
  WINUSB_INTERFACE_HANDLE InterfaceHandle,
  UCHAR                   PipeID,
  PUCHAR                  Buffer,
  ULONG                   BufferLength,
  PULONG                  LengthTransferred,
  LPOVERLAPPED            Overlapped
);

C#
internal static extern Boolean WinUsb_WritePipe(
    IntPtr InterfaceHandle, 
    Byte PipeId, 
    Byte[] Buffer, 
    UInt64 BufferLength, 
    ref UInt64 LengthTransferred, 
    IntPtr Overlapped);
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but I got an exception of type 'PInvokeStackImbalance'. And if I try to not catching PInvokeStackImbalance exception, on param LengthTransferred I have a value of 259. It is not correct because I send only 3 bytes on the channel. If I get the last error, I have INVALID_HANDLE issue but my handle is correct to get description and information about the USB device.